# splash screen y icon no se actualizan al hacer build de mi aplicación react native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, expo, build

estoy tratando de hacer el .aab y el .apk de mi aplicación de react native con eas-cli, todo se logra muy bien, pero a pesar de que cambio versiones en mi app.json y actualizo los directorios de imágenes, teniendo la aplicación instalada en mi teléfono usa los íconos y la pantalla de inicio que vienen por defecto con expo. Quisiera saber como hacer para que se actualicen, es decir que muestre la imagen que elegí para la splash screen y el iconó. ya comprobé que mis directorios esten bien

**app.json**

```
{
  "expo": {
    "name": "xooc-numeros",
    "slug": "xooc-numeros",
    "version": "2.2.1",
    "orientation": "portrait",
    "icon": "./assets/imgs/icon1.png",
    "userInterfaceStyle": "light",
    "splash": {
      "image": "./assets/imgs/splash1.png",
      "resizeMode": "contain",
      "backgroundColor": "#ffffff"
    },
    "packagerOpts": {
      "sourceExts": [
        "cjs"
      ]
    },
    "updates": {
      "fallbackToCacheTimeout": 0
    },
    "assetBundlePatterns": [
      "**/*"
    ],
    "ios": {
      "supportsTablet": true
    },
    "android": {
      "adaptiveIcon": {
        "foregroundImage": "./assets/imgs/adaptative-icon1.png",
        "backgroundColor": "#000000"
      },
      "versionCode": 3
    },
    "web": {
      "favicon": "./assets/imgs/adaptative-icon1.png"
    },
    "description": "Contar números en maya"
  }
}
```

**eas.json**

```
{
  "cli": {
    "version": ">= 0.52.0"
  },
  "build": {
    "development": {
      "distribution": "internal",
      "android": {
        "gradleCommand": ":app:assembleDebug"
      },
      "ios": {
        "buildConfiguration": "Debug"
      }
    },
    "preview": {
      "distribution": "internal"
    },
    "production": {}
  },
  "submit": {
    "production": {}
  }
}
```

Comment: No suena como una pregunta de git

Comment: @eftshift0 lo siento, ya lo corregi, me había equivocado